# Finding a redirected url to current php page via NginX rewrite or redirect

Tags: php, nginx, redirect

I am using nginx to redirect all non-exists subdirectories to another directory called '/report'. I do have a php file there to record IP address of the URI originator. Can I know the actual subdirectory my users initially tried to connect? In other words, is is possible to find out (using php) it the query was redirected or not?

Comment: Have you tried checking the contents of the `$_SERVER` var? It contains `HTTP_REFERER` and - while not totally reliable - usually contains the previous URL, and it may have it.

Comment: Yes, I have. HTTP_REFERER does not return anything.

Comment: In that case I don't think this is possible with just PHP (someone else might have an idea). I'd probably look at using some URL params in your Nginx redirect configuration, redirecting to `/report?dir=fooBar` and grab the value of `dir` via PHP that way. [Nginx docs has all the details if you go that way.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are making the rewrite/redirect.

Internal redirection using either [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) or [`rewrite...last`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) will not change the original URI (`$request_uri`) which is usually presented to PHP as `REQUEST_URI` in the `$_SERVER` var.